# Preventing LTS upgrade to another version of ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lts

I have several computers and people on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit and I would like to stay on that version. There use to be an option that says `LTS version updates only` (or something like that) now it says `always ask`, `default upgrade`, or `smart upgrade`.  Does anyone know what these options actually do.  I don't won't people accidentally upgrading to 18.10 when all they want to do is update and install software / security fixes.

[image]

Comment: What program is this window from? The options you are thinking of are found in the Software & Updates app and this isn't the stock 16.04 version of that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Questioner indicated he's using 18.04 64-bit -- that may be why the window doesn't match 16.04 Software & Updates.

Comment: Thanks. In my 18.04 it doesn't look like that either, but I use lxde. This looks like some gnome preferences app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been my understanding that either "Default Upgrade" or "Smart Upgrade" will accomplish what you want -- in that an LTS release won't automatically upgrade to a non-LTS version in any circumstances.  That is, 18.04 won't install 18.10 unless someone with admin privileges goes through some process to do so.

The difference between the two, if I've understood correctly, is that "Default Upgrade" only upgrades packages that have the same name in the repository, while "Smart Upgrade" may automatically install additional related packages or upgrade to a follow-on package with a different name, or may hold an upgrade if it'll cause problems with another installed package.

Answer (score 2):

I believe setting "Prompt=never" in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades will disable notifications about available upgrades all together.